# Printing the hex representation of an array of values

Tags: c, arrays, hex, type-conversion, printf

I was reading a program in C (an implementation of a server/client communication) and I saw this:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
 sprintf(nickmsg+i*2, "%02X", buf[i] & 0xFF);
```

What does this line do? I don't understand this especially: `nickmsg+i*2`.
`nickmsg` is a char table and `i` is an integer. If it was just `nickmsg`, ok I'll understand but there what's the aim of this line ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes/votes do close?  This is a perfectly reasonable beginner's question and an excellent example of typical idioms in C.

Comment: @AdamLiss Probably because the chance of anyone ever coming across this question in a search for their question is nil.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: Changing the title and tags makes the question easier to find, and not much more effort than downvoting.

Comment: The close is for "too localized".  I have no idea why.  Hex representation is the same everywhere, surely?

Comment: @AdamLiss Indeed I am sure it is. I didn't down vote, was just answering the question that was asked in the comments. But I will say that by changing the title, it has completely change the original question. The title answers the question originally asked. This question is now useful, but the question has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start at the address pointed to by `nickmsg` and then go an additional `i * 2 * CHAR_BIT / 8` bytes in memory. From there, write the hex representation of `buf[i] & 0xFF`, which will occupy `2 * CHAR_BIT / 8` bytes. Repeat for each `i`.

Assuming `buf` looks like

```
buf[0] = 20
buf[1] = 12
```

Then the memory pointed to by `nickmsg` will look like:

```
nickmsg
|
|
|
+ + + + +
0 2 4 6 8
140C\
```

Where the `\` is my nomenclature for the null-terminator that `sprintf` writes at the end.

Comment: As a visual example imagine you have `buf` containing `03|FE|B4` you will have nickmsg containing `00|03|00|FE|00|B4` afterwards

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` is written into the C standard, so you can assume it :)

Comment: On another hand, if `buf` is a char table, why do `& 0xFF` ?

Comment: @Eregrith No, `nickmsg` will contain `03F3B4`, followed by a null character.

Comment: Yes sorry, my mind got upside-down on the hex/char. `%02X` ensures `0x03` will be written `"03"` as characters, not `0x00 0x03` as hex XD. Duh.

Comment: @Eregith:  No, nickmsg will contain `30|33|46|45|42|34|00` because `%02X` converts to ASCII

Comment: @JeremyP: I think you're confused. `nickmsg` will be `"03FEB4"` in that case, assuming `buf` looks like `{ 0x03, 0xFE, 0xB4 }`.

Comment: @Jason: The hex bytes will be as I wrote them.  nickmsg written as a string will be as you wrote them.

Comment: @JeremyP: Gotcha. I didn't realize that's what you were writing; my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

It's converting the values in the `buf` array to their hexadecimal representation and storing them in the `nickmsg` array.

As it steps through each value in `buf`, it extracts the rightmost 8 bits by performing a bitwise `AND` with `0xFF`, which is binary `1111 1111`.

Then it uses the format string `"%02X"` to print each value as 2 hex digits.

It stores each pair of hex digits in the `nickmsg` array, then advances past them by using the index `i*2`.

Answer (score 1):

`nickmsg+i*2` is treating the nickmsg variable as a pointer to a C string table, then stepping through it 2 entries every loop.